# Picking elements to maximize a sum

Tags: algorithm

I have a 4 by n matrix containing positive integer values. I want to pick one value from each row so that we have  M_{1,j_1}, M_{2, j_2}, M_{3,j_4}, M_{4,j_4}  as the output subject to the following:

- The sum  M_{1,j_1} +  M_{2, j_2} +  M_{3,j_4},+ M_{4,j_4} is as large as possible.
- M_{1,j_1},< M_{2, j_2}< M_{3,j_4} <  M_{4,j_4}
- j_1 <  j_2 <  j_3 < j_4

Is there a fast algorithm for this?

Comment: Define "fast"; in particular, how much faster than the algorithm you came up with (which you forgot to share).

Comment: @ScottHunter I mean that is close to linear time. The only way I know is completely naive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with simple case of only 2 rows: sequentially increment j_2 and inspect every M_{2, j_2}, at the same time keep track of the optimal M_{1,j_1} value (largest M_{1,j_1} smaller than M_{2, j_2} for j_1 < j_2), find maximum sum of these values. If you need to extend this to row 3 and row 4, write this maximum (for each j_2) to some array.

An obvious way to obtain the optimal M_{1,j_1} value is to keep (constantly growing) binary search tree for values of M_{1,1} .. M_{1,j_2-1} prefix of the first row, and find predecessor for M_{2, j_2} value in this tree. But this leads to sub-optimal O(n log n) algorithm.

For O(n) time complexity we'll need a simpler data structure: a stack. Before adding some element of the first row to the stack, pop from the stack everything smaller or equal to the current element (this keeps the stack in strongly decreasing order). When searching for the predecessor of M_{2, j_2} value, also pop from the stack everything smaller or equal to M_{2, j_2} except the last such value and use it as optimal M_{1,j_1} value.

To add the third row, just apply the 2-rows approach to the maximum of first 2 rows and the third row. To add the fourth row, apply the same algorithm one more time.

The whole algorithm will scan the matrix 3 times, also it will push and pop elements to/from the stack up to 3*n times, so its time complexity is O(n). Additional space of O(n) needed to store 2 intermediate arrays could be eliminated if we compute prefix maximums on the fly. But we still need O(n) space for stacks. It is possible to solve the problem with O(1) extra space if it is allowed to destroy contents of the input matrix: just reuse its 3 rows for 3 stacks or one stack + 2 intermediate arrays (though implementation would be very tricky if you need to report indices of the optimal values).

Comment: This is a very nice and clean solution. Thank you.

Comment: Nice that you understood everything from the very beginning. Still I found that some important details were missing and updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could solve it in close to linear time for 2 rows, so doing so for 4 seems unlikely.

I'd think the best approach would be dynamic programming:  for each successive row (2..4), find the best sum you can compute for each element of that row (and which elements produced it, if need be), assuming you have already computed the best sum for the lower rows; then take the best of the sums for row 4.